# How can I construct a generic object with a reified type parameter in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, generics, kotlin-reified-type-parameters

I have a class called `Column<E>` that delegates to a `MutableList<E>`.

To sort the Comparable elements ("e") of columns without providing a comparator, I pass a reified type argument ("type") to determine whether e implements comparable using reflection and then use e's compareTo method to construct a comparator.  This all works fine.

I also have a function object called AggregateFunction that is used in reduce operations. AggregateFunction holds an actual function (to do the reduction operation), and a name (for programmatically creating a name for the result). There are several subtypes of AggregateFunction. NumericAggregateFunction, for example, takes an input column of type Column and always returns a Double.

The typical use case is to partition the input data into subgroups and return a Column containing the computed values for each subgroup. The catch is that I want to programmatically construct a column to hold the results. In the case of NumericAggregateFunction, I want to create a `Column<Double>`. For BooleanAggregateFunction, a Column`<Boolean>`, etc.

If I want Aggregate function to return a `MutableList<Double>` I can create it without a problem using:

```kotlin
fun resultList() : MutableList<OUT> {
    return ArrayList<OUT>()
}
```

However, the same approach fails to compile for Column, apparently because of the reified type. If I attempt to use the inline function, e.g.

```kotlin
fun resultColumnA() : Column<OUT> {
    return Column<OUT>("column name")
}
```

I get:

```
Cannot use 'OUT' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.
```

I also attempted to call the primary constructor directly, passing in the type parameter as shown below, it also fails to compile:

```kotlin
fun resultColumn() : Column<OUT> {
    return Column<OUT>(
            inputColumn!!.type, 
            "column name")
}
```

I now get the error:

```
Type mismatch. Required: OUT Found: Any!
```

Finally, I tried reifying the type parameter in the context of the Aggregate function, adding these two methods:

```kotlin
inline fun <reified OUT> col(nm:String) =
    Column(
        OUT::class.java,
        nm
    )

fun resultColumnB() : Column<OUT> {
    return this.col("name")
}
```

But the line `return this.col("name")` results in a compile time error:

```
Cannot use 'OUT' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead.
```

Is there a way to create a Column similar to how the MutableList was created?

If not, is there a way to determine whether the elements of a MutableList are comparable without using a reified type? If I didn't have to do that I could get rid of the type entirely.

Partial Implementation of class Column is included below

```
package com.fathom.core.tables

inline fun <reified E> Column(nm:String) =
    Column(
        E::class.java,
        nm
    )

open class Column<E>(val type: Class<E>, var name: String, val comparator : Comparator<E>? = null, val elements: MutableList<E?> = ArrayList()) : MutableList<E?> by elements{

    var formatter: (E?) -> String = { e ->
        if (e == null) "" else e.toString()
    }

    // when present, allows sorting on this vector without providing a comparator to the sort method
    var defaultComparator: Comparator<E>? = null


    /**
     * Returns true if elements contained in this column implement comparable.
     * That makes the column sortable
     */
    fun isComparable(): Boolean {
        return type.interfaces.contains(Comparable::class.java)
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns an int comparator where the ints are the indexes of the elements of the column rather than the elements.
     * It uses the indexes to get the values, which are then compared using
     * (a) a Comparator<E> column property named 'comparator', or
     * (b) the natural comparator for any column that implements Comparable
     *
     * @throws UnsupportedOperationException if the column has no comparator and doesn't implement Comparable
     */
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    fun rowComparator() : Comparator<Int> {
        if (comparator != null) {
            return Comparator { r1, r2 ->
                val v : E = get(r1) as E
                val f1 : E = this[r1] as E
                val f2 : E = this[r2] as E
                comparator.compare(f1, f2)
            }
        }

        if (!isComparable()) {
            throw UnsupportedOperationException(
               "Columns that are used in table sorts must either " +
                  "provide a comparator or contain elements that " + 
                  "implement comparable"
            )
        }

        return Comparator { r1, r2 ->
            val v : E = get(r1) as E
            val f1 : Comparable<E> = this[r1] as Comparable<E>
            val f2 : E = get(r2) as E
            f1.compareTo(f2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the definition of `Column` class?

Comment: @al3c I added the class after removing methods that don't use the reified type

Comment: You're using `Column` both as a function name and a class name that's confusing, I'd suggest changing the function name. Said that all the `Column` functions are `inline reified`  hence they can only be called from another inline reified function or from a location where `E` is known at compile time

Comment: FWIW: Using Column as a function name is deliberate so that the caller need not be concerned about whether they're calling a (factory) function or a constructor. That's an implementation detail library users shouldn't have to worry about.

Comment: Since @al3c says it's not possible to construct the Column with a reified type parameter I am falling back on removing the need for the type parameter in the first place. Instead of using it to check whether the elements are comparable, I am casting them to comparable  without previously checking, but doing it inside a try block and catching the exception where this fails.

Comment: Specifically, the issue is `resultColumn()` does not have a reified type to pass to the reified function it's calling. The class with the type `OUT` needs to have a concrete class type for `OUT`, just like your Column class does.